# what is the need to bind StringBuffer to synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, stringbuffer

I have one doubt. It is known that `StringBuffer` is thread safe (Its methods are `synchronized`) as opposed to `StringBuilder` which is not thread safe.

If `StringBuffer`, it self is thread safe, then why do I need to enclose it in `synchronized block` when modifying it. Below is the code:

```
class SyncTest extends Thread 
{   
    StringBuffer sb;

    public SyncTest(StringBuffer sb) 
    {
        this.sb = sb;   
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        synchronized(sb) 
        {
            for(int i = 1;i<=10;++i) 
            {
                System.out.print(sb);
            }
            sb.setCharAt(0, (char) (sb.charAt(0)+1));// incrementing the char by 1, thus modifying the StringBuffer
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("A");

        new SyncTest(sb).start();
        new SyncTest(sb).start();
        new SyncTest(sb).start();    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCC
```

When I remove `synchronized block` output changes and varies like below:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBBB
ACCC
```

So, what does it mean, when we say that `StringBuffer` is thread safe. Can anyone clear my doubts regarding this?

Comment: The _individual operations_ of a `StringBuffer` are thread safe; two operations, one after the other, are not. Note that the same stands true for a `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 4):

You're performing a compound operation. You're both displaying it and modifying it. In itself both operations are thread safe, but when combined like that, they're not.

One thread can modify the contents while another thread is displaying the individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuffer` being synchronized means that each method invocation is synchronized, but two successive invocations are not.

If you do

```
sb.append("Hello Dolly");
```

You are guaranteed that no other operation will append anything in the middle of the two words.

If you do

```
sb.append("Hello ");
sb.append("Dolly");
```

The `sb` could end containing `Hello whateverDolly`.

The only way to avoid the former is perform the synchronization in the context where it is needed.